# 2001 Pontiac Grand Am cooling fans not kicking on

Tags: pontiac, fan, cooling, grand-am

I just bought a 2001 Pontiac Grand Am SE for 1,500 and registered in 3 days ago.  My luck it’s  been one thing after another. (I guess you really do get what you pay for) Pulled into a parking lot & parked, My engine started smoking & my anti freeze was pissing out everywhere. My radiator cap had a hole drilled in it to relieve pressure build up with whoever doing it not realizing that it would just piss out everywhere. So I had that replaced. Now the reason for that is because my cooling fans are not kicking on. Is it even worth fixing for 1,500? Should I go and get my money back? Not to mention the exhaust had a piece of pipe put in and was never welded on. Oh joy.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What engine do you have and are you sure that the fans not coming on is your only problem?  This means you should only experience problems when idling such as when you're stuck in traffic. The pcm doesn't command the fans on until 226 f, so that puts your temp gauge at about 3/4 hot.  The reason I ask is you have stated some very 'sketchy' previous repairs, and drilling a hole in the radiator cap seems more like a way to try to let combustion gasses out from a failing headgasket.  Just a thought when it comes to your actual question about being worth it, or getting refunded.

Comment: I have a V6, I’m not a mechanic but know a little because I work at a dealership BUT the entire car has electrical issues that I can tell you. Ended up getting the cooling fans to kick on low but it was cold and rainy so getting them to kick on high wasn’t happening. Once I got them

Comment: Once I got them working, my left blinker slowed down to normal speed but my right one still blinks twice as fast. There’s also an aftermarket horn in there wired and mounted under my steering wheel .

Comment: It is just right here on the picture, take a look,! G103, G105, and the other grounds, cool no! I just find one corroded on the connector ( motor blower ) and the other on the motor blower resistor, green corrosion and a sticky connector, and find after 45 min on a runtime engine, the main fuse and relay circuit deffect by a hot relay, temp check Innova 3340a or a temp gun, heavy wiring voltage drop, i remember i can ear it at idle,kick off the cooling fan, the alternator bearing ,the motor blower, the power steering pump bearing, and keep 2 amps more than the normal, on a amps clamp, of a Ac

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 components that can cause this.

1. Coolant temp sensor
2. Fan relays(s)
3. Defective cooling fans, there are 2 on that model.

More than likely on that old of a car the fans or relays have failed.

[image]